# Retrieve first child from a parent in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an Android application. I want the first child (first UID) of the parent 'support' and store it in a String variable. How do I get the value of the first UID from the list?
I tried one approach. It doesn't work though.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
    if (dataSnapshot1.exists()) {
        String futureUID = "";
        for(DataSnapshot futureUIDdatasnapshot:dataSnapshot1.getChildren() ){
            futureUID = futureUIDdatasnapshot.getKey();
            break;
        }
        /*Getting the first UID from the list of UID's in queue in 'future'*/
        futureUID = dataSnapshot1.getChildren().iterator().next().getKey();
        /*Moving a card from 'future' to 'serving'*/
        societyServiceUIDReference.child(FIREBASE_CHILD_SERVING).child(futureUID).setValue(FIREBASE_ACCEPTED);
        /*Removing the UID from 'future' after it is placed in 'serving'*/
        societyServiceUIDReference.child(FIREBASE_CHILD_FUTURE).child(futureUID).removeValue();
    }

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
```

NOTE: 'futureUID' is the UID I want

[image: Firebase structure]

Comment: did u tried any code if yes thed post it

Comment: Updated with code

Comment: This logic will never be stable.  In example what happens if someone adds another user in support?  Considering data is always changing and mutating it's best to think of it like this "how can I structure my data to achieve such and such"

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("support");
Query queryUid=ref.orderByKey().limitToFirst(1);
queryUid.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String key=datas.getKey();
            }
        }

 @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: for shows a warning here, because quite obviously it doesn't loop

Comment: here its looping inside ids of  the child `support` and it will retrieve the first id according to the query..

Comment: It is looping, and its returning all the UID's in the list one by one. Order is correct but the number of UID it returns is wrong. I want only one UID.. Not all.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

> .orderByKey().limitToFirst(n) is what does the trick. It orders the query results by key and returns only the first n results; in this case 1

```
mDatabase.getChild("support").orderByKey().limitToFirst(1)
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener () {

      @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
              for (DataSnapshot supportItem: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              String futureUID =supportItem.getKey();
            }
        }

    }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
         //Catch your error here
    }
});
```

see [Work with Lists of Data on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)

Comment: for shows a warning here, because quite obviously it doesn't loop

Comment: have you tried logging the dataSnapshot object to your console? Use dataSnapshot.toString()

Comment: It is looping, and its returning all the UID's in the list one by one. Order is correct but the number of UID it returns is wrong. I want only one UID.. Not all.